# Javascript make asynchronous calls inside a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using an inside loop based on the user id. Below code, response take more time. anyway to other parallel requests code available ??

````
  return request("https://example/userlist")
    .query({
      page: 1,
      offset: 20,
    })
    .get()
    .json(async res => {
      var promises = [];
      let result;
      res.map(entry => {
        promises.push(fetchUserDetails(entry.id));
      });
      result = await Promise.all(promises);
      return result;
    });
}

export function fetchUserDetails(story) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(`/user/details/${story}`)
      .get()
      .json(response => resolve(response));
  });```
````

Comment: I suggest for loops, always use promise.each rather than any other way

Comment: Promise.all will finish once you get all apis resolved or either any of one is rejected

Comment: `var promises = []; res.map(entry => { promises.push(...) })` - You might want to have a second look at the documentation of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS : right, can we use Async / await?

Comment: async await will be helpful if you have some dependency on the above promise i think in your case promise.all will be better